# RuntimeLocalServer.exe when debugging?

Tags: .net, arcgis, esri

I'm just trying to get started in working with ESRI's ArcGIS runtime for .NET.

I have a simple hello-world app that's working fine, loading a tile package into an ArcGISLocalTiledLayer:

```
<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">
    <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap">
        <esri:ArcGISLocalTiledLayer ID="BaseMap" />
    </esri:Map>
</esri:MapView>

var basemapLayer = this.MyMap.Layers["BaseMap"] as ArcGISLocalTiledLayer;
basemapLayer.Path = @"E:\EsriMaps\MapPackages\MyMapData.tpk";
```

But when I try to change this to use a map package:

```
<esri:MapView x:Name="MyMapView">
    <esri:Map x:Name="MyMap">
        <esri:ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer ID="BaseMap" />
    </esri:Map>
</esri:MapView>

var localMapService = new LocalMapService(@"E:\EsriMaps\MapPackages\MyMapData.mpk");
await localMapService.StartAsync();

var basemapLayer = this.MyMap.Layers["BaseMap"] as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
basemapLayer.ServiceUri = localMapService.UrlMapService;
```

I get an exception:

```
_HResult=-2147024894
_message=LocalServer start failed: executable not found.
HResult=-2147024894
IsTransient=false
Message=LocalServer start failed: executable not found.
Source=Esri.ArcGISRuntime
FileName=E:\dev\experiments\ESRI\HelloWorldMap\HelloWorldMap\bin\Debug\arcgisruntime10.2.7\localserver32\bin\RuntimeLocalServer.exe
```

There is a arcgisruntime10.2.7 in my bin\Debug folder, but there's no localserver32 folder within it. Any ideas as to why not?

There is a copy of RuntimeLocalServer.exe in my C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\bin, but somehow I don't think I'm supposed to be copying it over manually.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is simple enough.

ArcGIS runtime puts a Deployment.arcgisruntimemanifest file in the project. If you open this you'll be in a manifest editor that allows you to select "Local Server" as one of the packages to be deployed.